# Internal Server Error 500 When setup web on subdomain : CakePhp

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, hosting, shared-hosting

Here is my folder structure:

```
Root/
sub.domainname.com/
 .htaccess
 app/
  .htacess
  webroot/
   .htacess
httpdocs/
 .htaccess
```

I'm trying to set up a subdomain for my application but server return error:500 when I call sub.domain.com

I think I config .htaccess incorrect and I have no idea to fix it to work! help me please.

*in httpdocs folder is main web files on domain >> www.domainname.com but files in this folder not Cakephp framework it's use Wordpress and in sub.domainname.com is subdomain web files to use Cakephp framework.

*I use shared hosting (http://netdesignhost.com/) lookalike GoDaddy Hosting.

Dear Variables and all ... this my .htaccess

cakephp/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

cakephp/app/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /app/
    RewriteRule ^$ webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

cakephp/app/webroot/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /app/
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(app/webroot/)?(img|css|js)/(.*)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

This's error logs

```
[Sun Sep 17 23:38:45 2017] [alert] [client 184.22.122.56] /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/sub.domain.com/.htaccess: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters, referer: http://sub.domain.com/

[Sun Sep 17 23:42:18 2017] [error] [client 184.22.122.56] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

thank you.
Pea.

Comment: Please post the content of `cakephp/.htaccess`, `cakephp/app/.htaccess` and `cakephp/app/webroot/.htaccess` and your http error logs, since HTTP Status Code 500 is a generic error message. Most likely the _RewriteBase_ is not set correctly.

Comment: I post new answers already thank for reply me : ))

Comment: Variables , I posted my .htaccess and error logs do you have idea :))

Comment: I'm not sure here; Try to remove the `RewriteBase /app/` from both files and test. If this is not working try to remove `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(app/webroot/)?(img|css|js)/(.*)$` for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a good idea to start with a simple 'hello world' HTML page in what you think is the subdomain root, and put is there on its own, to make sure the subdomain works properly *before* adding in anything else.

Another issue is: most servers I've seen would need the folder structure to be slightly different:

```
Root/
 sub.domainname.com/
  httpdocs/   /* sub-domain site */
   .htaccess
   app/
    .htacess
    webroot/
     .htacess
 httpdocs/ /* main site */
  .htaccess
```

So instead of putting all your subdomain code (`.htaccess` and `app` folder) directly into the subdomain folder, you put it into an `httpdocs` folder *inside* the subdomain folder.
But do try with just a simple HTML file first.

Comment: Thank you for reply me, I'll try use your solutions and comeback to tell about result :))

Comment: I try with your solution already... but it stay error 500 and this's a logs error  

[Sun Sep 17 23:38:45 2017] [alert] [client 184.22.122.56] /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/sub.domain.com/.htaccess: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters, referer: http://sub.domain.com/

[Sun Sep 17 23:42:18 2017] [error] [client 184.22.122.56] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.